# Every four consecutive integers contains one which cannot be written as sum of two squares

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Every four consecutive integers contains one which cannot be written as sum of two squares.

Could anyone advise me how to prove the statement? Do I use Jacobi's two squares theorem? Hints will suffice, thank you.

Comment: Out of four consecutive integers, one is congruent to $0$ modulo 4, one is congruent to $1$ modulo 4, one is congruent to $2$ modulo 4, and one is congruent to $3$ modulo 4.

Comment: Hint: What are the squares mod 4? What are the possible values for sums of two squares mod 4?

Answer (score 3):

Hint:

- There is a number of the form of $4k+3$.
- You might like to explore $x^2 \pmod{4}$.

Answer (score 0):

You may consider the following as a **hint**:

Squares are of the form $4k$ or $4k+1$ "easy to verify $(2k)^2$,$(2k+1)^2$". Now, what are the possible forms of the summation of these numbers?

Comment: It seems that numbers of the form $4k+3$, which occurs in every four consecutive integers, cannot be written as sum of two squares.

Comment: which proves the statement. is not it?

Answer (score 0):

One further hint: Consider that Pythagorean triples $x^2+y^2=z^2$ can be found as $x=m^2-n^2,\space y=2mn,\space z=m^2+n^2$.